# Image Watermark MiniMagick & Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, watermark, minimagick, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am trying to watermark the product images from a model. I have set static images for testing but I am getting an error and I don't understand why.

Can anyone assist in why I am getting this error:

> undefined method `composite' for "CIAO12.png":String

Current Setup:
Rails 5.2
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8' (Included in the Gemfile)

Brew install imagemagick (Successful)

Code is testing on static images but will be change to the product image instead of the 'CIA012.png' image.

Show Action

```
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title"><%= @product.product_name %></h5>
  <% if @product.image.attached? %>
   <%= image_tag(@product.watermark) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Product Model

```
def watermark
  first_image  = "CIAO12.png"
  second_image = "watermark.png"
  result = first_image.composite(second_image) do |c|
    c.compose "Over"    # OverCompositeOp
    c.geometry "+20+20" # copy second_image onto first_image from (20, 20)
  end
  result.write "output.jpg"
end
```